# Import suncalc in cloudflare worker

Tags: javascript, cloudflare-workers

I have been trying to get suncalc to work in a cloudflare worker, however `require` is not supported by cloudflare workers and `import` doesn't work on suncalc. Has anyone run into this as well and found a solution?

Been trying many different ways of importing, however unfortunately without any success.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me

```js
const suncalc = require("suncalc")
//..

const times = suncalc.getTimes(new Date(), 51.5, -0.1)
```

Wrangler prints out a warning, but despite that I can still use the library with no issues

```
▲ [WARNING] Converting "require" to "esm" is currently not supported [unsupported-require-call]
```

Comment: If it doesn;t work for you I suggest copying the functions from `suncalc` repo into your codebase